# How to correctly set QextSerialPort for Windows

Tags: serial-port

I'm regularly using QextSerialPort for Serial Communication on Linux (Ubuntu); I'd like to transfer my code to Windows, but it seems to be a problem related to the QExtSerialPort library use.
Here's my function:
void ts400::EsuPortSetupDNI()
{
    this->EsuPort = new QextSerialSleeperThread::msleep(TIME_STEP);Port("/dev/ttyS0", QextSerialPort::EventDriven);   // Serial Port

```
 EsuPort->flush();
 EsuPort->setBaudRate((BaudRateType)BAUD4800);
 EsuPort->setFlowControl((FlowType)FLOW_OFF);
 EsuPort->setParity((ParityType)PAR_NONE);
 EsuPort->setDataBits((DataBitsType)DATA_8);
 EsuPort->setStopBits((StopBitsType)STOP_1);

 if (EsuPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) == true)
 {
     connect(EsuPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyReadDNI()));
     ui->EsuReturnLabel->setText("Ready to receive serial data");
     EsuPortFlag = SET;
 }
 else
    ui->EsuIdentlineEdit->setText("SERIAL NOT PRESENT!");
```

}

I tried to replace the first line:

```
this->EsuPort = new QextSerialSleeperThread::msleep(TIME_STEP);Port("/dev/ttyS0", QextSerialPort::EventDriven);   // Serial Port
```

with one , in my opinion, for Windows:
    this->EsuPort = new QextSerialPort("COM1", QextSerialPort::EventDriven);   // COM1

Compiling, result are a lot of errors; seems to be related to Linux use...

Any idea?